# Dynamically Loading and Removing Javascript Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a way to inject a new JavaScript functions dynamically without having to do a page reload. I have a form for putting in inventory items and I would like to load or remove functions based on which manufacturer is selected. Trying to research this I thought I could accomplish this with:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild
```

The document I was using for examples was taken from http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml. At first I was not sure if it was calling the file and so as a final test I appended the small snippet:

```
var petname="Spotty"
alert("Pet Name: " + petname)
```

and to the end of the .js file and received the alert. I was hoping to make this input page modular and dynamic. The reason I need to replace the functions is because each manufacturer uses what is called a "BOM" number which based on the values gives the unit model, condenser, electrical, etc. The scripting as it stands right now uses the onChange feature so on each drop down selection the BOM number is updated with its correct value. Conversely entering in a BOM number will select the values from the drop down menus. The JavaScript functions work as intended with the onChange's if I place it in the 'head' but when using the .appendChild none of the functions work. Should I be using something else for this?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to your problem is call a single function which accepts BOM number and manufacture type. Then fetch your unit model, condenser, electrical based upon the manufacture type
Javascript:

```
function GetDetails(bom, manufactureType){
   switch(manufactureType){
         case 'blah blah' : <do something>
     break;
default:break;
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select onchange="javascript:GetDetails(<pass selected BOM here>, <pass selected MANUFACTURER here>);"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this library will help you http://yepnopejs.com 
Using it you are able to load and execute JS files after some conditions.